# Is it possible to save top entity using InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

For example we have such a structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public class A{
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "B")
public class B{

}
```

in most of tutorials was mentioned that for saving an entity we should save B entity.

```
B b = new B();
b.setName("name");
entityManager.persist(b);
```

Is it possible to use the Top entity class, not the subclass while saving? Something like this:

```
A a = new A();
a.setName();
a.setType("B");
entityManager.persist(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save ANY Entity. The only thing to remember with inheritance is that you set the strategy in the ROOT table and can't override it in subclasses.

Note that you should set a `DiscriminatorValue` on the root type too (if saving instances of that type)

Comment: if you notice, I want to save the Root entity, but with Discriminator value of the SubEntity. If you are saying that i can save ANY entity, can you please tell me in more details, how should I specify discriminator value of the SubEntity while saving the Root entity?

Comment: I notice you call "setType" but can only assume you have some other field called "type". When you save a RootEntity you obviously CANNOT set the discriminatorValue since it is not a field in the object. The DiscriminatorValue is a surrogate field managed by JPA only, not you. A RootEntity is not a SubEntity.

Comment: So the answer is: No there is no possibility to specify concrete type (e.g. type of the subclass) while saving Root entity. Thank you.